# angularjs directive use parameter inside link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is probably a stupid question, but I have been stuck on it for days and neither of the googled solutions panned out for me.

I'm writing an angular 1.4 app following a directive driven approach, so for any entity I have one or more widgets:

- isolated scope
- controller as
- bindToController true

The problem is of the "user has stuff" variety.

```
<user-widget>
   <stuff-widget userid="user._id"></stuff-widget>
</user-widget>
```

The userid passes nicely into the widget, but I would like to use it inside the stuff widget's link function, because stuff is really complicated and in the real world I need to grab various other parts as well.

I tried various methods to get to the userid value (as suggested in various other stackoverflow discussions and elsewhere on the web)

- use bidrectional binding -> not effective
- tried via scope and controller -> userid, uid not defined
- require ^userWidget -> lost access to my controller
- use attrs.$observe('userid', ....) -> js error: userid not defined
- passed it via pre link of the parent -> did work, but not a good idea/limited merits

I have a plunker with the various things I tried: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqlhYSteCDxMaAVZWCsy?p=info

The widgets look like this (working pre link variant)

```
  function userWidget() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope:{},
      template: '<h2>User</h2> {{user.name}}<stuff-widget userid="user._id"></stuff-widget>',
      replace: false,
      controllerAs: 'userCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: 'UserCtrl',
      link: { // this actually works, not sure wether this a good idea
        pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          var uid = 1;
          scope.user = ctrl.findById(uid);
          scope.userid = scope.user._id;
    },
    post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {}
      }

    };
  }

  function stuffWidget() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        uid: '=userid'
      }, 
      template: '<h3>User stuff</h3>stuffCtrl.userid inside widget: {{stuffCtrl.userid}}<div ng-repeat="stuff in stuffCtrl.userStuff">\
User id: {{stuff.userid}}: {{stuff.stuff}}\
</div>',
      replace: false,
      controller: 'StuffCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'stuffCtrl',
      bindToController: {
        userid: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    console.log('stuff ctrl userid:', ctrl.userid); // not defined
    console.log('stuff scope uid:', scope.uid); // not defined
    console.log('Scope parent userid: ',scope.$parent.userid); // undefined

    // didn't work either - userid not defined
    /* attrs.$observe('userid', function(value) {
      if (value) {
        ctrl.userid = userid;
        console.log('stuff ctrl userid observed:', ctrl.userid);
      }
    }); */
    ctrl.userStuff = ctrl.findByUserId(ctrl.userid);
      }
    };
  }
```

I'm an angular beginner (first serious project) and so far my experience has been: "if it's hard to figure out, you are probably doing it the wrong way".

So,

- Did I miss an obvious way to access the param inside the link function?
- Did I screw up the ways I tried (especially $observe) because I incorrectly transferred them to my setting?
- Should I just stick the controller calls inside the template and be done with it?
- Should I go about it in an entirely different way? compile function? controller function? whatever other angular depths I'm not yet familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the link function has finished its execution you will have to wait one **digest cycle** to update the values in the isolated scope from the scope  where the directive is used.

You can try this snippet in **stuffWidged**:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  var uid, usrStuff;

  scope.uid; // it is normal to be undefined here

  scope.$watch('uid', function(newUid) {
    uid = newUid;

    scope.uid; // is ready and is same as newUid

    usrStuff = ctrl.usrStuff = scope.usrStuff =
      ctrl.findById(uid);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Notice that it is **scope.$watch** not **attrs.$observe**
http://plnkr.co/edit/xJQy73urjpEIyWccPx8v?p=preview

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much! It finally works. I didn't figure out that I had to put the id assignment and ctrl.call inside the watch function as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove isolated scope from user-widget - do u really need it there? If you are not defining any additional variables in directive scope - you do not actually need isolated scope.
2. Isolated scope. So user-widget should have some parameters? Like:

> ```
> <user-widget widgetusers="model.users"></user-widget>
> ```

then user-widget template will be:

> ```
> <stuff-widget ng-repeat="stuffuser in widgetusers" userid="stuffuser._id"></stuff-widget>
> ```

3. You can pass userId first to userWidget, then to stuffWidget:

> ```
> <user-widget userid="user._id">
>    <stuff-widget userid="userid"></stuff-widget>
> </user-widget>
> ```

Comment: I don't have a problem accessing the data on the parent, I have a problem accessing the parameter value inside the stuff directive link function. Doesn't work for a a hardwired value like <stuff-widget userid="0"></stuff-widget> either.

Comment: it wont work for userid="0", since u define '=' in directive, so it requires two-way binding, hence variable not a value. If u define it like '@' it should work with constant. (then for variable u should use ="{{varname}}")